# Querying mysql database with SQLDeveloper doesn't return correct values

Tags: mysql, encoding, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a mysql database with a charset `utf8` of all the tables.
I am using SQLDeveloper to access and query the database with the latest JConnector JDBC driver.

When executing a simple query such as `SELECT 'Варна';` equivalent to `SELECT 'Варна' from DUAL;`, which contains Bulgarian language, SQLDeveloper returns `'?????'`. This makes  selects from the database in which I have used Bulgarian language return `NULL`, because their `where` clauses (containing Bulgarian language) mismatch the `uft8` Bulgarian characters in the database. (When the select doesn't use Bulgarian language at all SQLDeveloper returns completely correct values and displays the Bulgarian language returned as a result of the query correctly.)

The `Preferences -> Environment -> Encoding` in SQLDeveloper is set currently to `UTF-8`, but I have tried virtually every applicable encoding listed in there and even the simplest query `SELECT 'Варна' from DUAL;` still does not return back the correct value `Варна`.

I have looked into setting the variable `NLS_LANG`, thinking this may be the cause but to no avail. (Perhaps it is the key after all but I am unable to actually configure it properly).

Edit: In order to reproduce the problem and visualise it (as I realise I may have explained it poorly) just go in SQLDeveloper and connect to a mysql database and execute the query `SELECT 'Варна' from DUAL;`.

Edit2: Clarifications.

Edit3: As shown by the comment left by @tenhouse it appears that this may be a bug.

Edit4: As stated below as a comment, the above query `SELECT 'Варна' from DUAL;` works perfectly fine without any modifications and/or settings fiddling on MySQL Workbench.

Edit5: Please, feel free to correct the title and/or tags if you feel that something can be improved as there is still no answer to the problem.

Edit6: By now can I assume that it really is a bug? Could anyone advise me where exactly to report it - is it a JConnector or SQLDeveloper related bug. I would think that I have to report it as a SQLDeveloper bug but I'd rather get a confirmation before possibly wasting their time.

Edit7: Tried to clarify it even further in my hopes for an answer.

**Edit8: (Important!)** My current database is hosted on linux (Ubuntu 12.04, MySQL 5.5.28) server. If, however, I install MySQL on a fresh Windows machine and create a `utf8` db there, querying through SQLDeveloper works as it is supposed to, `SELECT 'Варна' from DUAL;` actually returns `Варна`. Could someone please confirm this?

Comment: I don't understand the problem; I also don't use SQLDeveloper but the [MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/). If I create a table with charset UTF-8 and insert some cyrillic or mandarin letters, the I can select them via a WHERE-clause without any problems. My connection also used UTF-8. What does "which contains Bulgarian language (Windows-1251)" mean? Are you storing Windows-1251 data inside UTF-8 tables? This would mangle any character…

Comment: When using MySQL Workbench everything seems to work completely fine. The db is utf8, the data in the db is utf8, the queries are utf8, everything is great. Now, when using SQLDeveloper, however, the db is utf8, the data in it is utf8, the queries I am not certain about and don't know how to fix it, I suspect SQLDeveloper automatically uses a certain encoding to encode its queries and as that is probably not utf8 it makes such a problem

Comment: FYI: I just tested the whole thing with utf8 db, mysq-connector 5.1.22, Oracle SQL Developer 3.1.07 and I have the same results as you. Maybe it's a bug.

Comment: I am using Oracle SQL Developer Version 3.2.20.09 so I suppose it is either a bug or maybe there is something neither of us knows how to setup in order to actually get the correct results.

Answer (score 1):

So I didn't know this myself till having this problem a few months back, but MySQL actually offers the ability for different encodings for clients, databases, and connections. MySQL will convert (or collate) the requests/responses from/to a client to different encodings as specified by the client or in his config file. So even though the database is storing stuff as utf8, if the client is set to latin1, your going to see latin1 as your result encoding. The easiest way to check this is to spin up a connection to MySQL and run the following query:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%char%";
```

You should see a whole bunch of encodings for different connections/sources. From your description, I imagine most of these will *not* be utf8. Here's [mysql's doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-connection.html) on what each of these mean. You can test if this in fact the problem by doing a **SET NAMES 'utf8';** or **charset utf8;** (can't remember which one) and running your queries again to see if that fixes the problem.

A summary of what each of these guys does (since the docs leave some stuff out):

- **character_set_client:** specifies how data is encoded when sending from client to server. Anything connecting through MySQL's API is *not* a client (ex. php's mysqli, most C/C++ wrapper libs)
- **character_set_database:** specifies the encoding for data stored in the database
- **character_set_filesystem:** not really sure, but I believe how data is written to disk?
- **character_set_results:** the encoding that MySQL returns query results
- **character_set_server:** server's default set (not really sure cases where this is used)
- **character_set_system:** not sure on this one either
- **character_sets_dir:** where your collation/encoding definitions are located

Most of these guys can be specified by editing your my.cnf and sticking your defaults in there.

I'm not exactly sure how JConnector works, but I imagine it uses MySQL's C API, in which case you'll need to do something like the following somewhere in the code. Maybe JConnector has a way for you to set this through him. I'm not sure, but here's the syntax for the MySQL API:

```
mysql_options( myLink, MYSQL_SET_CHARSET_NAME, "utf8" );
```

**EDIT:** For MySQL 5.5

Answer (score 0):

You can try a command like this ::
ALTER DATABASE CHARACTER SET WE8ISO8859P5;

Please restart the DB after changing the characterset.

More details refer this link where it explains about the encoding required for different languages

http://www.csee.umbc.edu/portal/help/oracle8/server.815/a67789/ch3.htm

Comment: `ALTER DATABASE CHARACTER SET WE8ISO8859P5;`
returns `Error report:
SQL Error: Unknown character set: 'WE8ISO8859P5'`. Please note that the database is not an Oracle database but a MySql database.

Comment: Can you please try this one ::
alter database  dbname 
character set cp1251
collate cp1251_bulgarian_ci
The query is working fine in MYSQL workbench did you try it there??

Comment: I have tried it, still, to no avail. I specifically copied a table over to a new database and changed the charset as you have shown above in order to do that. The query definitely works on MySQL Workbench, however I have an issue there with a mouse cursor going crazy, so I cannot use it properly in order to do my work.

Answer (score 0):

after you connect with a mysql_connect:

```
$dbcnx = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass)
```

you do this query:

```
mysql_query("SET 
                  character_set_results = 'utf8', 
                  character_set_client = 'utf8', 
                  character_set_connection = 'utf8', 
                  character_set_database = 'utf8', 
                  character_set_server = 'utf8'", 
    $dbcnx);
```

Now this will set the encoding for what is returned, what happens on the server - so all of it has the same encoding.

In your following query's, you specify this connection to be used

Answer (score 0):

Export

Add `[?characterEncoding=utf8]`

```
<StringRefAddr addrType="customUrl">
    <Contents>jdbc:mysql://instance_host_name:3306/database_name?characterEncoding=utf8</Contents>
</StringRefAddr>
```

Import